# Wrapbootstrap implementation explained

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I purchased and downloaded a front-end bootstrap file and I purhcased an admin file. I downloaded them fine but I was looking through the files and it seems a lot more complicated than i thought. I thought it was going to be simple html/css/js files that I could just copy over to my file path. Could someone explain to me how to use wrapbootstrap with my own project?

Also, I've noticed A LOT of people asking about using WrapBootStrap with Rails App and other applications but I wasn't planning on doing that. Can someone just explain to me the process of using the wrapbootstrap.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to contact the theme author to see if there are missing instructions, generally there are instructions in the themes.

In general, Wrapbootstrap is a theme marketplace where many developers/designers sell themes using the Bootstrap's css and html and adding their own styles and additions. Purchasing a theme from that marketplace, or any other marketplace, assumes that you are familiar with html and css and how to create a site with it using your particular CMS (Wordpress, Drupal, ModX, Statamic, CMS Made Simple, Text Pattern, and so forth), and it assumes basic skills like using your ftp client or ssh.

If you are not a developer and are just wanting to create your own, small static page web site with it, you will need to learn some web basics, http://teamtreehouse.com/ has inexpensive courses. There is plenty of free instruction online too.

Generally speaking, if you have already created a Boostrap based site in html using their default css, you can replace (after you make a backup of all your stuff) the CSS from the theme, as long as the versions of Bootstrap are the same, this should work. You can then take a look at their additional scripts and see what you want to add to your current set up.

Comment: Does that mean I'm required to have a CMS in order to use a bootstrap theme? I was under the impression that the theme was going to be some HTML,CSS and JS files in which I can customize on my own. However, my assumption clearly is wrong (my fault ofcourse) so I was wondering if I'm goign to need to purchase/download some CMS.

Comment: You can make a static site, if it's not too complicated and doesn't require a database (a blog, for example, requires a database or a flat file to pull the information from), then you can make a static site, though you have an admin theme, so why did you buy that?